# Como carregar os pares latitude e longitude para um objeto C# e trabalha-los?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, google-maps, javascript

Boa noite!
Estou desenvolvendo uma página web onde o usuário pode traçar uma rota.
Uso a api google maps.
Preciso pegar os pares latitude e longitude da rota, carregar para um objeto c# e, após trabalhar as informações da latitude e longitude, devolver a lat. e long. para o google Maps colorir a rota de acordo com as informações que irei devolver.
Por exemplo:
quando eu devolver latitude: -12.123, longitude: 13.123 eu preciso que seja colorido de acordo com um peso que vou passar. Por exemplo, se o peso for menor que 5, aí colore de amarelo, maior que cinco, de azul.
Vou postar o meu código que gera a rota para quem sabe vocês me ajudarem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function InitializeMap() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.9412735, -44.07623219999999);
        var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionpanel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('startvalue').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('endvalue').value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
    function Button1_onclick() {
        calcRoute();
    }
    window.onload = InitializeMap;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o [objeto GeoCoordinate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx) em `System.Device.Location` que serve justamente para trabalhar com coordenadas.

Ele possui os métodos [`Latitude`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.latitude(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`Longitude`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.latitude(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pela ajuda, mas tenho pouco conhecimento de javaScript e C#, por isso ainda tenho dificuldades para resolver o meu problema, pois preciso obter as coordenadas da rota e, antes de gerar a rota para o usuário, trabalho as informações e, de acordo com o resultado do que eu fizer, aí eu preciso traçar a rota com cores diferentes em cada trecho de acordo com um valor. Não estou conseguindo progredir neste sentido, poderia me dar uma ajuda com esse problema, ou me indicar um material ou exemplo na web mesmo que seja similar?
Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Confesso que não conheço bem a API do Google Maps, mas em teoria seu código funciona. [Achei este link que pode ajudar](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-V3-Draw-route-line-between-two-geographic-locations-Coordinates-Latitude-and-Longitude-points.aspx).

Comment: Estou estudando ele e parece que vai me ajudar.
Muito obrigado Cigano.